# Combining 'order' with flexbox 'row-reverse' to achieve desired dynamic layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to achieve a container which wraps from looking like this:

```
<div style='display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 100px; border: 1px solid !important;'>
  <div class='title' style='border: 1px dotted;'>Title text long</div> 
  <div class='size' style='border: 1px dotted;'>Large</div>  
  <div class='price' style='margin-left: auto; border: 1px dotted;'>£4.00</div>
</div>
```

[image]

To look like the below when the title is shorter

[image]

One method I had hoped would work is to use a type of `row-reverse` on the main flex container, and a `order: -1;` on the title div, but the order doesn't override the row-reverse. I've been playing around with options for a while now and am beginning to wonder if its even possible with CSS-only. A JS solution would still be useful, but CSS-only would be much preferred, if even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can adjust the HTML code, float can do it:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid ;
  overflow:auto; /* to clear float */
}

.box > * {
  border:1px dotted;
  float:left;
}

.box > .price {
  float:right;
}

.size {
  clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" >
  <div class='title' >Title text long</div>
  <div class='price' >£4.00</div>
  <div class='size' >Large</div>
</div>

<div class="box" >
  <div class='title' >Title text</div>
  <div class='price' >£4.00</div>
  <div class='size' >Large</div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="width:250px;">
  <div class='title' >Title text</div>
  <div class='price' >£4.00</div>
  <div class='size' >Large</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a good idea. the only downside is as you demonstrate in that third box where it all wraps to one line when its wide enough for all three elements. For my use I would want this staying on the bottom even when the container is wide enough for all three, but as I said I don't know if this is possible only with CSS. Thank you

Comment: @DevOverflow you want `large` to always stay at the bottom?

Comment: Yes for my use; the whole container is to be used underneath a product thumbnail.

Comment: @DevOverflow it's even easier in this case, check the update